# How to setup prerender in angular js project?

Tags: angularjs, prerender

I am tryting to setup prerender on my angular js project. Following is the .htacess config for my project

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token mytokeniscorrect

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Googlebot|Google.*snippet|LinkedInBot|bingbot|Yahoo|MSNBot|YahooSeeker|baiduspider|rogerbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|Slackbot|Slack-ImgProxy|Slackbot-LinkExpanding|Site\ Analyzer|SiteAnalyzerBot|Viber|WhatsApp|Telegram|woobot|woopingbog/1.1) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://view9.com.au:3000/http://development.view9.com.au/stage/captivation-sport/captivation_v3/$2 [P,L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

But when i test with woo rank or google master i see the following result.

[image]

Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong??

Comment: You shouldn't check Googlebot by their user agent. Feel free to send us an email at support@prerender.io with your website address so we can help test things for you.

Comment: i am generating the meta tags dynamically but when bot renders it cache the page before waiting for http request. Can you please tell me how to increase cache time ??

Comment: You shouldn't need to increase the cache time since we can wait pretty long for the page to render. Can you send us an email with a URL where you are experiencing this so we can check for any javascript errors?